# Game of life in Python: Issue with the function that return the next step of the game

Tags: python

The program consists of 3 main parts: Finding the numbers of Neighbors, creating a list with the rules of the game of life, and one last part which converts 1/0 into True or False.

The issue is that it seems to return a good answer, but when I evaluate my program in my teacher's website, It says that it returns a wrong answer.
Here is the code:

```
python
from typing import List
import copy as cp
def next_step(pop: List[List[bool]]) -> List[List[bool]]:
    ''' renvoie la prochaine population '''
    L=[[0]*len(pop) for x in range(len(pop))] #init
    M=cp.deepcopy(pop)
    #coins
    L[0][0]=pop[0][1]+pop[1][1]+pop[1][0]+pop[0][-1]+pop[1][-1]+pop[-1][-1]+pop[-1][0]+pop[-1][1]
    L[0][-1]=pop[0][0]+pop[1][0]+pop[-1][0]+pop[0][-2]+pop[-1][-2]+pop[-1][-1]+pop[1][-1]+pop[1][-2]
    L[-1][0]=pop[0][0]+pop[0][1]+pop[-2][0]+pop[-2][-1]+pop[-1][1]+pop[-1][0]+pop[-1][-1]+pop[-2][-1]
    L[-1][-1]=pop[0][0]+pop[0][-2]+pop[0][-1]+pop[-2][0]+pop[-1][0]+pop[-2][-2]+pop[-2][-1]+pop[-1][-2]
    #bords
    for i in range(1,len(pop)-1):
        L[0][i]=pop[0][i-1]+pop[0][i+1]+pop[1][i]+pop[1][i-1]+pop[1][i+1]+pop[-1][i]+pop[-1][i-1]+pop[-1][i+1]
    for i in range(1,len(pop)-1):
        L[-1][i]=pop[-1][i-1]+pop[-1][i+1]+pop[-2][i]+pop[-2][i-1]+pop[-2][i+1]+pop[0][i]+pop[0][i-1]+pop[0][i+1]
    for j in range(1,len(pop)-1):
        L[j][0]=pop[j-1][0]+pop[j+1][0]+pop[j][1]+pop[j-1][1]+pop[j+1][1]+pop[j-1][-1]+pop[j][-1]+pop[j+1][-1]
    for j in range(1,len(pop)-1):
        L[j][-1]=pop[j-1][-1]+pop[j+1][-1]+pop[j][-2]+pop[j-1][-2]+pop[j+1][-2]+pop[j][0]+pop[j-1][0]+pop[j+1][0]

    #milieu
    for u in range(1,len(pop)-1):
        for v in range(1,len(pop)-1):
            L[u][v]=pop[u-1][v-1]+pop[u-1][v]+pop[u-1][v+1]+pop[u][v-1]+pop[u][v+1]+pop[u+1][v-1]+pop[u+1][v]+pop[u+1][v+1]

    for k in range(len(M)):
        for i in range(len(M)):
            if L[k][i]==3:
                if pop[k][i]==False:
                    M[k][i]=True
            elif L[k][i]==2:
                if pop[k][i]==True:
                    M[k][i]=True
            else:
                M[k][i]=False
    for k in range(len(M)):
        for i in range(len(M)):
            if M[k][i]==0:
                M[k][i]=False
            if M[k][i]==1:
                M[k][i]=True
    return M
```

Comment: can you please format your code so that it's readable in the question?  Use ``` triple backtick to surround the code

Comment: Hey, I think that it works with ~~~, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Is the field supposed to be a rectangular area ? If so, the calculation of the corners' and edges' number of neighbors seem off: you count the 8 neighbors as if the field wrapped unto itself.

Comment: both ``` and ~~~ work but `'''` does not.  Single quote `'` is not the same as backtick `

Comment: Hi, The field is a square !

Comment: Yes, but is it supposed to wrap unto itself (like a torus), or should the corners have only 3 neighbors and the edge cells only 5 ?

Comment: It supposed to be a torus, there is always 8 neighbors !

Comment: Ok then, the problem isn't there.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the rule where a live cell with 3 neighbors survives is missing: if so, the rules should become:  if L[k][i]==3: M[k][i]=True  (no need to test whether the cell was live or not before).

Comment: You're absolutely right, however, it still marked as False on my teacher's website...

Comment: Then I'll fill an answer for future reference :)

Comment: Btw, I just realized (by answering another question) you could deal with corners, edges and inner cells with the same code: from cell (i,j) you can define left_i = i-1 if i>0 else -1, and define right_i, above_j and below_j in similar ways.

Comment: There is also another way, it is to say that c, the number of neighbor is the sum of L[i%n][(j+1)%n] + L[i%n][(j-1%n)] .......... My problem was fixed,tho the website was at fault, I reset eveyrthing, and then it worked, without changing a line of code. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Indeed, using modulo does it more quickly (and more importantly elegantly); glad to hear your problem was solved and it wasn't your fault.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from one of the rules (a live cell with 3 neighbors survives) not being actually implemented.

Here's a fix for the relevant part of the code:

```
# Implementation of the rules

for k in range(len(M)):
    for i in range(len(M)):
        # A cell with 3 neighbors will survive, or be born
        if L[k][i]==3:
            M[k][i]=True
        # A live cell with 2 neighbors will survive
        elif L[k][i]==2:
            if pop[k][i]==True:
                M[k][i]=True
        else:
            M[k][i]=False
```

Comment: It still won't work :( ... I'm very grateful for your help tho. Maybe his website is broken or something

Comment: Can you test your program by implementing a visual representation of the cell matrix, and using classic GoL figures (square, glider, bar...) ?

Comment: Yeah I can do that, there is also a gui...

Comment: It should be quite easy then, and you only need a small matrix (5x5 for example) to test those shapes. Btw, your last step (converting 0s and 1s in M) seems unnecessary, since you already fill M with booleans.

Comment: The weird thing is that everything seems to work : gliders, blinkers and all that stuff ...

Comment: Have you tested all the edges and corners (it could be a typo somewhere); if all works as intended, it might be a flaw in your teacher's test protocol, so you'd better ask them.